# What is the git command for the action to be considered at the remote repository after I deleted a tracked file?

Tags: git

There is a tracked file that we do not need anymore. I deleted the file on my local repository. So what are the `git` commands to write in order for the action to be effective on the remote repository ?

Comment: has deleting the file locally not allowed for staging the deletion for remote??

Comment: Are you asking for `git push`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+delete+file

Answer (score 1):

#### Untrack the file

If you don't want `git` to track a file you have to can untrack it with

```bash
git rm --cached filename
```

Then you will need to commit the changes locally with:

```
git commit
```

After that you can push the changes to the remote with:

```
git push
```

#### Delete the file

If you want to delete a file, simply remove it from the repo.

Add the changes with:

```
git add -A
```

You can check the changes with `git status`:

```bash
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    file.md
```

Then you can commit your changes with:

```bash
git commit -m "Removed the file"
```

To push the changes on the remote:

```bash
git push
```

Comment: my goal is not to untrack the file, but really make the deletion of the file to be passed on at the remote repo : I want the file to be deleted also at the remote repo.

Comment: do I have to make a `git add deleted_filename` before `git commit` ?

Comment: no : `git status` gives `Changes not staged for commit  ->  deleted : path/to/the/deleted_filename`

Comment: Add the changes with `git add -A `

Comment: it is `git add -A filename` but not just `git add -A`